# How many lines do you usually have on a page?

Tags: margins, geometry, layout

from what I read 75-80 characters per line should be the optimal for the human eye to scan. Leslie Lamport makes a mention about this: https://haroldpboas.gitlab.io/courses/math696/LaTeX-customizing-page-layout.html

I'm currently using the Charis SIL font at 11pt and 1.5" left and right margins. A4 paper.

Page 1:

[image]

Page 2:

[image]

I'm not sure how tall should be my top and bottom margins. Is there any rule to follow on how many lines per page should be optimal? At the moment I use 1" top and bottom margins, but as you can notice there are many lines on the second page.

Comment: Please show  the tex code you used to create the screenshots ...

Comment: Since you seem to know how to set the spaces, this is not really a TeX question. Anyways, [this document](https://ftpmirror1.infania.net/mirror/CTAN/info/memdesign/memdesign.pdf) by P. Wilson is a nice read on the subject of laying out the page.

Comment: Thank you. The author seems to use quite large headers and footers in his PDF.

Comment: The answer will probably be: "comfortable", like shoes. It will depend. I usually zoom (standard 14pt) and minimize scrolling.

Comment: @mickep Do you have any idea what font the author uses in his book? It looks very nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that there are any rules regarding the optimal number of lines per page. One suggestion (from Mitchell & Wightman "Book Typgography" ISBN 0 948021 66 7) is between 32 and 38 lines. However the actual page size, the size of the font, the readership, etc., will all have an effect. A book for young children will have fewer lines per page than one describing scientific theories.

Go with what you thinks looks good for your publication.