# 65-75 characters per line is easier for me to read but side margins are large

Tags: margins, geometry, paper-size, layout

I have a document that has 1.8" left and right margins allowing me to adhere to the 65-75 characters per line rule which is considered to be the optimal line length for the human eye to scan. Leslie Lamport, the creator LaTeX, mentions it on this page: https://haroldpboas.gitlab.io/courses/math696/LaTeX-customizing-page-layout.html

My document uses the Charis SIL font at 11pt which is nearly the same size as the
"Times New Roman" at 12pt. Perhaphs the Charis SIL is a notch smaller but the added legibility of the Charis compensates nicely for the size difference.

The problem is that the left and right margins are large on A4 paper.

[image]

Comment: Please post `MWE` also...

Comment: I think this question, as well as [your previous one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656119/how-many-lines-do-you-usually-have-on-a-page), are interesting. But are they about TeX? This is more about typesetting, in general. Or do I misread? Do you have a concrete TeX question?

Comment: I was wondering in which forum should I post my question.

Comment: Use a twocolumn layout to have easy readable lines and normal page margins.

Comment: @dexteritas I think I'll keep the large margins.

Comment: Currently, you have 12 cm text width (21-2*4.5). You could also make the page landscape and then use `twocolumn`. Something like 1.8 cm left border, 12 cm text, 2 cm middle space, 12 cm text, 1.8 cm right border, if you want to print it and use the page better.

Comment: that's why professional single column publications never use A4.

Comment: Print on narrower paper?

Comment: @DavidCarlise  I think A5 would be better. Isn't it? I switched my article class to A5 by using `\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}` and `\special{papersize=148mm,210mm}` and wow now everything looks so amazing. The margins aren't as wide and the text is easy to read. I'm not sure if A5 is supported in the `article` class that's why I added the `special` macro.

Comment: avoid using `\special` it limits you to dvips so you can not use pdflatex etc, use `a5paper` and `geometry` package